# Starling + Box2D - setLinearVelocity not strong enough

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, box2d, box2d-iphone, starling-framework

I made a small billiard game with FlashDevelop using Starling and Box2d for the iPad Retina screen.

setLinearVelocity() does not give me desired results for the billard break.

I use the standard approach:

```
    var vx = shotStrength * Math.cos(shotAngle);
    var vy = shotStrength * Math.sin(shotAngle);

    var vel = _whiteBall.GetLinearVelocity();

    vel.x += (vx);
    vel.y += (vy);

    var force = new b2Vec2(vel.x, vel.y);
    _whiteBall.SetAwake(vel);
   _whiteBall.SetLinearVelocity(force);
```

With this approach, even setting the shotStrength to 10000 does not make
the shot very strong on break.

What do I do wrong?

Mirza

Comment: First up: `setAwake()` accepts a boolean not a number.

Comment: thx, checked that corrected to true but still the same

Comment: What is the mass of the objects you're trying to displace? Also, is there friction on the surface?

Comment: fixtureDef.density = 0.1;
   fixtureDef.restitution = 0.7;
            fixtureDef.friction = 0.5;

Comment: How about with a higher restitution, like 0.98 or so? I feel friction should be lower too... are they set to be bullet bodies?